# using regex match gets error cannot read property "0" from null

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I trying to write some code, that splits a string into an array by a given delimiter, and then runs a regex match on each element of that array to try and extract relevent data. In the example below I would hope that on the first time round the loop I would get "8934" in my TestString and on the last round "23423". Instead I get an error stating: TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from null (#6).

```
var myStr = "H$ello8934 My23 Name1 Is76 Frank789 $ello23423";
var myArray = myStr.split(" ");
for(i = 0, l = myArray.length; i < l; ++i) {
    var testRegex = /\$ello(\d+)/;
    var testGet = myArray[i].match(testRegex);
    var TestString = testGet[0];
    alert(TestString);
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You split the string with a space, and feed the split chunks to the regex. You do not check if a regex matched the string. However, when a regex does not match, the result of `String#match` is *`null`*.

The code checks `H$ello8934` and returns a match, then it finds `My23`, and does not find the match, and returns the error.

Check if the regex found a match:

```js
var myStr = "H$ello8934 My23 Name1 Is76 Frank789 $ello23423";
var myArray = myStr.split(" ");
for(i = 0, l = myArray.length; i < l; ++i) {
    var testRegex = /\$ello(\d+)/;
    var testGet = myArray[i].match(testRegex);
    if (testGet) {
     var TestString = testGet[0];
     alert(TestString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you my plan was to test if TestString was Null - I hadn't realised I needed to check that the array wasn't Null itself.